# Alternative to table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I creating a page with table. I would like to break a word for responsive.
Here is my CSS code,

```
body{
        border:0px;
        margin:0px;
        width:100%;
        padding:0;
        height:100%;   
    }
    #container{
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .right-panel {
        -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
    }
    .left-panel{
        width:220px;
        min-height:100vh;
        background-color:#222;
    }
    .right-panel{
        min-height:100vh;
        background-color:#eef0ed;
    }
    table{
        width:100%;
        word-break: break-all;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        table-layout: auto;
    }
    td{
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .left{
        float:left;   
    }
    .right{
     float:right;   
    }
    .clear{
     clear:both;
    }
```

and here is my HTML code,

```
<body><div id="container"><div class="left-panel">
 </div><div class="right-panel"><div id="content">
        <div class="container-table">
            <table class="tb">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Pasdaddadadad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        SPasdaddadadad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        DPasdaddadadad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        LPasdaddadadad
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        APasdaddadadad
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        POPasdaddadadad
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        PePasdaddadadad
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        MaPasdaddadadad
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        asdadadadadada
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        asdadadadadada
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div></div></div></body>
```

I used word-break.
I set it break-all, but it is not working.
I also used word-wrap.
I set it break-word, but still not working.

I tired table-layout:fixed.
I think this line make it work. But there is a problem.

In my layout, table should be in the right side. 
But when I used table-layout:fixed, It go down and occupied 100% width of the page.

How can I make it stay in the right side?
Or any alternative to table-layout?

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` is working fine, [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/3ssje4LL) what exactly do you want?

Comment: Try to put the HTML code here: <body><div id="container"><div class="left-panel"></div><div class="right-panel"> .... INSIDE HERE .... </div></div></body>